# React component within Vaadin 14

Tags: java, html, reactjs, components, vaadin

Can someone help me how I can integrate react JS components into Vaadin 14 as a new Java component? Unfortunately I have not found any useful example what can help in creation. I'd like to use in a Java code react-resizable ro re-resizable in a DIV. Thx.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: There are really two questions here: how to integrate a React component in Vaadin and how to make a resizable `<div>`. In general, it's preferred to use browser features over external libraries when possible in Vaadin apps. In this case, you can use the [resizable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) CSS property to make a div resizable. You can use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver#browser_compatibility) if you want to listen for changes.

Comment: Marcus! Thx, the resize with css was a good advice and it works. Upcoming subject is to get the actual size of resized component. Do you have any experience with this? I tried "getElement().executeJS('resize', .....)" but unfortunately it was not so successful. The best solution would be to use the ClientCallable callback because the result is necessary  on server-side in Java.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but you should be able to use the ResizeObserver and pass the result back to the server with a ClientCallable. You may want to throttle the call to the server so you don't bombard it with every pixel change, only the final size.

Comment: Thx Marcus! In the meanwhile I have solved this issue. The solution is close to your suggestion only the JS side made some obstacles.